# Exported variable 'SAlert' has or is using name 'AlertInterface' from external module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, alert

I'm using antd alert component (ts) with styled component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Alert from 'antd/es/alert';
    
export const SAlert = styled(Alert)`
  && {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
  }
`;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYfhQ.png)
and on npm i getting following error:

```
 Exported variable 'SAlert' has or is using name 'AlertInterface' from external module
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx2wu.png)

In some articles I've read that it's because of the import name but I've imported different ways. e.g

```
import {Collapse as MyCollapse} from 'antd';
```

and still got the same error
I see that antd is not exporting AlertInterface and this is causing the issue.

```
interface AlertInterface extends React.FC<AlertProps> {
    ErrorBoundary: typeof ErrorBoundary;
}
declare const Alert: AlertInterface;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIcCF.png)

1. Can you tell me why antd is not exporting interface for some components and does for others?
2. What is the best way to solve this error?
   Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution to not duplicate interface export:**

```
    import { ComponentType } from 'react';
    import { AlertProps } from 'antd/es/alert';

     export const SAlert = styled<ComponentType(AlertProps)>(Alert)`
      && {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
        border-radius: 14px;
        border: 0;
        padding: 8px 12px;
      }`;
```